# Confusion about pointer to an array as a function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In my textbook about c++ I have the following code example:

```
  using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    int main() {
        int aArr[4] = { 3,4,2,3 };
        int bArr[3] = { 2,3,1 };

        cout << "Append: " << endl;
        printArray(aArr, 4); cout << " + "; printArray(bArr, 3);
        int* cArr = append(&aArr, bArr);
        cout << " = "; printArray(cArr, 7); cout << endl;
        return 0;


    }
```

Does the "&" symbol in front of "aArr" in the call to append in main mean that the address of aArr is passed, or that a reference to aArr is passed.

The question then asks for me to implement a function append which takes two arrays: the first array (in the first argument) of size 4 by array pointer and the second array (in the second argument) of size 3 by reference and returns a pointer to an array of size 7. I have declared that function as (in the appropriate header file)

```
int* append( int foo[4], int (&secondArray) [3] );
```

Has the author perhaps misplaced the order of the "&" symbol in the append method (that it should be in front of "bArr")?

Comment: &aArr and aArr is the same thing in fact, special case for static arrays.

Comment: Read about *references*. The ambersand means different things in different contexts. In the context of a variable declaration (like argument declarations are) it's not the address-of operator, but means that the variable is a *reference*.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant No they are not the same thing in fact!

Comment: @Barry: the address will remain unchanged at least, or i was 100% wrong ? ( i mean &aArr and aArr value is still the adress of the first case of the array)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so in this context it is a reference?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant An array is an memory location that contains an address. So if they are the same thing then how would you pass the address of that array? (i.e. the address of the array memory location).

Comment: The author did not misplace anything, and `&aArr` passes the address of the array (which is a pointer). Your attempt at `append` expects a the address of the array's first element, so you will need to change it to syntax which expects the address of the whole array.

Comment: @M.M how about  int* append(int(*firstArray)[4], int(&secondArray)[3])

Comment: @JamesDickens looks good to me, see what the compiler says (make sure warnings are enabled)

Comment: @jussij: you can get the address of a static array, you will alway get the first case of the static array, because it is fixed during the compilation. You can only get the address of pointers, which addresses aren't predetermined during the compilation.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant. No. You can get the address of anything and that is exactly what the & symbol tells the compiler to do. &x means get address of x and x can be anything.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b23db0369d4b2157). These aren't the same thing. The address of `aArr` is the same as the address of its first element, but the type of `&aArr` is pointer to array of 4 `int`s, not `int*`.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can help you out in cases like this.

Lets assume that this is the function prototype for your append function:

```
int* append( int foo[4], int (&secondArray) [3]);
```

I can test this out with this simple bit of code:

```
int* append( int foo[4], int (&secondArray) [3])
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int aArr[4] = { 3,4,2,3 };
    int bArr[3] = { 2,3,1 };
    int* cArr = append(&aArr, bArr);
    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like this, failing with this error:

```
test.cpp(9): error C2664: 'int *append(int [],int (&)[3])': 
          cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (*)[4]' to 'int []'
```

As you can see it doesn't like the `&aArr` argument 1 at line 9 as it does not match the argument 1 defined by the function at line 1. From the error message it is even nice enough to give a reason why it thinks they don't line up.

Now using the hint from the compiler it is clear the function should in fact look like this:

```
int *append(int (*foo)[4], int secondArray[3])
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int aArr[4] = { 3,4,2,3 };
    int bArr[3] = { 2,3,1 };
    int* cArr = append(&aArr, bArr);
    return 0;
}
```

With that change the compiler is happy to accept the code as correct.

Now comparing the two you can see the difference is in the first case the first argument was passed as an array of 4 integers, whereas in the second case it is passed as the address of an array of four integers.

Just from the english you can tell these are two very different things.

**EDIT:** Here is an extension of that example that shows how to access the data inside the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *append(int (*foo)[4], int secondArray[3] )
{
    int *foo1 = *foo;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("foo: %d\n", foo1[i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        printf("secondArray: %d\n", secondArray[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int aArr[4] = { 3,4,2,3 };
    int bArr[3] = { 12,13,11 };
    int* cArr = append(&aArr, bArr);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling an running this code produces this output:

```
foo: 3
foo: 4
foo: 2
foo: 3
secondArray: 12
secondArray: 13
secondArray: 11
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Suppose that I want to loop over the elements in foo, how can I do this. This code is not working:    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  cout << *foo[i];

 }

Comment: @JamesDickens `(*foo)[i]`